# relaycommand CanExecute returns incorrect value

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light, relaycommand, canexecute

I create a pretty standard MVVM Light RelayCommand, with the canExecute parameter being:

> () => (customer.Regions.Count > 0)

when necessary I call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged();` and the canExecute is not reevaluated correctly. I then also call it manually like this: `var canExecute = myCommand.CanExecute(null);`, and it is still wrong. In the next statement right after I do `var foo = (customer.Regions.Count > 0)`, which returns the correct result. What is going on here?

**Command definition:**

```
SaveCustomerRegionsCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveCustomerRegions, () => (customer.Regions.Count > 0));
```

customer is a private property set when the class is instantiated.

Comment: This is really odd, everything looks right. Have you tried creating a CanExecute method to avoid using a lambda expression? I know it's a longshot, but when you are stuck everything is worth a try.

Comment: Yeah it works with a method, but I have other commands that work just fine with lambdas. If I use a relaycommand I created myself, it works just fine, it's just the MVVM Light one that fails.
_canExecute has an internal property IsAlive, which is false. maybe this is the reason? then the question becomes why is it false..

Comment: can you share code where you are defining your relay command, I mean method...

Comment: You should raise a different question regarding this behavior of MVVM Light's RelayCommand. Since my suggestion is working I'm posting it as an answer, hope you are ok with it to calify it as the solution. Regards

Comment: Have you tried () => true? Is it working? If its working then replace the lambda expression with something else.

Comment: sounds like the RelayCommand is losing its reference to the method. Since it is a Lambda, is it going "out of scope"? When you define an actual method it is working so that seems the issue. Take a look at the MVVM Light code, is it holding a reference to the canExecute function? If not, that might explain

Answer (score 0):

(from comment)
Create a CanExecute method to avoid using a lambda expression.

Looks that the IsAlive property of the MVVM Light Framework is interferring somehow, as you suggest. You can post another question regarding that if you like. Regards!